# In grails what does the syntax "static isNear = [ places:Places]" do?

Tags: grails

I am trying to make a isNear relationship and i was wondering what this would do?

static isNear = [ places:Places]

as

static hasMany = [ places:Places]

makes a has many relationship i was just wondering what happens if i replace hasMany with isNear?

Comment: Since it's not a supported syntax, I'd think it would just remove the has many relationship and create an ignored static property

Comment: Ok thanks I thought as much but figured I would ask.

Comment: Not sure why having another static map in the class would "remove" the hasMany relationship.  isNear would just be ignored, no?